# Signing algorithm 'ES256' is not supported with gamegos/php-jws

Tags: php

I want in PHP generate the decoded array of a jws and hopefully verify it so I do:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
include_once 'base.php';

public function decode($string, $key) {
    $jws = new \Gamegos\JWS\JWS();   
    return $jws->verify($string,$key);
}
```

But I get a fatal error: Uncaught Gamegos\JWS\Exception\UnsupportedAlgorithmException: Signing algorithm 'ES256' is not supported. So is there either a class somewhere available which `implements \Gamegos\JWS\Algorithm\AlgorithmInterface` (with sign and verify methods as stated in the doc https://github.com/gamegos/php-jws#exceptions) or either a lib which do the job with quite the same logic(for jws not only jwt)

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: That library is over 7 years untouched. I would recommend something more up-to-date. You can find some ideas here -> https://jwt.io/libraries?language=PHP

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer i will check the libs you've linked